# unable to create ExtJS5 panel UI

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am trying to create a panel with different color header than the regular one. Since there are going to be panels with different header colors, I decided to create different uis for each of them. Here is a sample code for one of them:

@include extjs-panel-ui(
            $ui: 'darkgreen',
            $ui-border-color: $panel-light-border-color,
            $ui-body-border-color: $panel-light-body-border-color,
            $ui-header-border-color: $panel-light-header-border-color,
            $ui-header-font-family: $panel-light-header-font-family,
            $ui-header-font-size: $panel-light-header-font-size,
            $ui-header-font-weight: $panel-light-header-font-weight,
            $ui-header-color: $panel-light-header-color,
            $ui-header-background-color: #666,
            $ui-header-text-transform: $panel-light-header-text-transform,
            $ui-tool-background-image: $panel-light-tool-background-image
        );

after creating it and building my application I included a panel with ui: 'darkgreen' but there is no effect. On the contrary the panel has no css applied.  Can someone point out where is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your component has `framed: true` (which is the case of the panel) you should create your UI as -framed.
Try the code below: 
* Just a quick note, you should change the name of your UI, but in the panel declare `ui: 'darkgreen'`

```
@include extjs-panel-ui(
    $ui:"darkgreen-framed",
    $ui-border-color: $panel-frame-border-color,
    $ui-border-radius: $panel-frame-border-radius,
    $ui-border-width: $panel-frame-border-width,
    $ui-padding: $panel-frame-padding,
    $ui-header-color: #FFF,
    $ui-header-font-family: $panel-header-font-family,
    $ui-header-font-size: $panel-header-font-size,
    $ui-header-font-weight: $panel-header-font-weight,
    $ui-header-line-height: $panel-header-line-height,
    $ui-header-border-color: $panel-frame-border-color,
    $ui-header-border-width: $panel-frame-header-border-width,
    $ui-header-border-style: $panel-header-border-style,
    $ui-header-background-color: #666,
    $ui-header-background-gradient: $panel-header-background-gradient,
    $ui-header-inner-border-color: $panel-frame-header-inner-border-color,
    $ui-header-inner-border-width: $panel-frame-header-inner-border-width,
    $ui-header-text-padding: $panel-header-text-padding,
    $ui-header-text-margin: $panel-header-text-margin,
    $ui-header-text-transform: $panel-header-text-transform,
    $ui-header-padding: $panel-frame-header-padding,
    $ui-header-icon-width: $panel-header-icon-width,
    $ui-header-icon-height: $panel-header-icon-height,
    $ui-header-icon-spacing: $panel-header-icon-spacing,
    $ui-header-icon-background-position: $panel-header-icon-background-position,
    $ui-header-glyph-color: $panel-header-glyph-color,
    $ui-header-glyph-opacity: $panel-header-glyph-opacity,
    $ui-header-noborder-adjust: $panel-header-noborder-adjust,
    $ui-tool-spacing: $panel-tool-spacing,
    $ui-tool-background-image: $panel-tool-background-image,
    $ui-body-color: $panel-body-color,
    $ui-body-border-color: $panel-body-border-color,
    $ui-body-border-width: $panel-frame-body-border-width,
    $ui-body-border-style: $panel-body-border-style,
    $ui-body-background-color: $panel-frame-background-color,
    $ui-body-font-size: $panel-body-font-size,
    $ui-body-font-weight: $panel-body-font-weight,
    $ui-body-font-family: $panel-body-font-family,
    $ui-background-stretch-top: $panel-background-stretch-top,
    $ui-background-stretch-bottom: $panel-background-stretch-bottom,
    $ui-background-stretch-right: $panel-background-stretch-right,
    $ui-background-stretch-left: $panel-background-stretch-left,
    $ui-include-border-management-rules: $panel-include-border-management-rules,
    $ui-wrap-border-color: null,
    $ui-wrap-border-width: null,
    $ui-ignore-frame-padding: $panel-ignore-frame-padding
);
```

I've done this, and it worked for me
[image: Panel with darkfgreen UI]